# Whitelist not working in Ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, whitelist

The app gets json data from a php script on some server. it workes fine on my laptop, but does not work on the android phone.

I have this in my config.xml file

```
<access origin="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

It looks like the whitelist does not work.. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any explicit error on the chrome console when your app is running ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly remove whitelist plugin by **cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-whitelist**, then install by **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist**. Finally, add these tag in your index.html file 
`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos;; script-src &apos;self&apos; &apos;unsafe-inline&apos; &apos;unsafe-eval&apos;">`

Comment: I did this, and no results, I got into the console of the app and no errors :/
11-18 18:42:45.637 D/ViewRootImpl(32355): ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
11-18 18:42:45.717 I/InputDispatcher(  848): Delivering touch to (32355): action: 0x1, toolType: 1

Answer (score 0):

A while ago cordova changed to a more restrictive whitelisting method.
Since then you need to install [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to be able to access external resources.

The fact that things are working on your labtop and not on the mobile points in this direction as well.

Comment: when i run that comand in console i get that i already have that package installed